# array of objects send through href

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to send some data through href tag, I`m using template literals, it works fine with strings and simple objects, but with an array doesn't seem to be working.

This is the link

```
 const link =`https://wa.me/number?text=Thanks%20for%20your%20purchase%20${input.name}!%0A${items}%0AName:%20${input.name}%0AAdress:%20${input.addess}%0APhone:%20${input.Phone}%0ACity:%20${input.city}%0ATotal:%20$${total}`
```

This is the JS, and I am not really sure if it's okay to use template literals here.

[code snipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdNbR.png)

```
const items = cart && cart.map((p, i) => {
    return(
      `<div>
      <h4>${p.title}</h4>
       <div>
           {p.salsa && p.salsa.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
       </div>
       <div>
           {p.toppings && p.toppings.map(item => item)}
       </div>
       <h4>${p.quantity}</h4>
       <h4>${p.Comments}</h4>
      </div>`
    )
})
```

Comment: You may need to add a little more context, but from a general viewpoint, I think there is probably a better way to send that data along then in the url. Is this going to another page within the same site?

Comment: The two snippets seem unrelated. In the second one, assuming this is actually React and you want to return JSX, you don't need a template literal to do it. Get rid of the backticks and enclose JS inside plain curly braces.